# How to unpack multiple identical tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
dictionaryofinputs = {'0':[0,0],'1':[2,1],'0':[5,1],'1':[20,1]}
```

How do i make a new dictionary made out of all of values with a key of one? 
i tried something like this:

```
 for item in dictionaryofinputs.values():
      if key[0] == '1'
          locationcoor = locationcoor + key[1]
```

but it did not work

thanks for your help, I am just starting out with python

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Furthermore the above is *non-sensical*: in a dictionary a key maps to exactly *one* value. So you can not add two entries with `'1'` as key.

Comment: The datastructure `dictionaryofinputs` cannot exist in Python as you posted it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the output that I would like is locationcoor = [[2,1],20,1]

Comment: @a.l: the point is that your `dictionaryofinputs` can *never* exist, since one of the two values will already be erased upon *construction* of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary uses a series of unique `keys` to identify a single or set of `values`. How you have your dictionary defined above will only return the second instance of the `0` and `1` `keys`. Your `value` can have repeated data, but not your `key`.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Additionally, your dictionary `values` are lists, not tuples. It is important to know the difference as tuples are immutable objects, and lists are mutable objects.

```
my_tuple = ('value1', 'value2')
my_list = ['value1', 'value2']
```

If you wanted to create a new dictionary using the `key` and `value`:

```
my_old_dict = {
    '0':[0, 0],
    '1':[2, 1],
}

my_new_dict = {}

for key, value in my_old_dict.items():
    if key == '1':
        my_new_dict[key] = value

print(my_new_dict)  #<-- PRINTS {'1': [2, 1]}
```

> ADDITIONAL INFO:

You code above:

```
for item in dictionaryofinputs.values():
    if key[0] == '1'  #<-- THERE IS NO KEY, YOU DID NOT UNPACK ONE.
        locationcoor = locationcoor + key[1]
```

is not complete, and one of the biggest reasons it is not working is because you are not unpacking a key with your values. It should be

```
for key, value in dictionaryofinputs.items():
    if key == '1':
        locationcoor[key] = value
```

assuming that `locationcoor` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Such dictionary can not exists, as `keys` are unique but this would be possible if that were a list of tuples like so `lst = [('0',[0,0]), ('1',[2,1]), ('0',[5,1]), ('1',[20,1])]` or same for list of lists.  We can use `sort`, `groupby` and a dictionary constructor

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [('0',[0,0]), ('1',[2,1]), ('0',[5,1]), ('1',[20,1])]
lst = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
lsta = []
for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0)):
    x = list(g)
    lsta.append((k, x[0][1] + x[1][1]))
d = dict(lsta)
# {'0': [0, 0, 5, 1], '1': [2, 1, 20, 1]}
```